# How to sign the jar files in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have created an artifact of type .jar in Intellij IDEA. It works properly, but I have to sign it afterwards manually. Batch file maybe a way, but I want to know if Intellij IDEA can do it by itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an ant task as post-process step in the artifact dialog. You then can use SignJar http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/signjar.html.